# How to make footer stick to bottom despite size of content?

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

I have this CSS code:

`#main-wrapper {min-height: 300px;}`

`#main {}`

`.clearfix:after {content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}`

I tried : clear:both; bottom:0; position:fixed; width:100%; for footer ..

but it works only in short content display .. when a content of a page is too long, then I have to scroll page down over footer ..

please help

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

Comment: it's only make it bigger not sticky

Comment: this question has been answered many times on SO. Please search before posting.

Comment: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ is the best solution I have found so far. Of course it won't work on older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see the example code here](http://jsfiddle.net/ptz8shsv/)

HTML

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="content"> content of any length</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#content {
    margin-bottom: 30px;/*same as footer height*/
}
#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    height: 30px;
    background: #eee;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Footer will always stick to bottom even content overflows the screen

Answer (score 0):

A simpler a neater way to do this:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="content">Main content</div>
    <footer>Footer content</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#content {
    min-height: 50vh; /*adjust to find the one that suits your content*/
}
```